# Quadratic Expression. Bugs

Tags: javascript, expression, quadratic

I am a beginner in JavaScript programming and this is my first project. I am trying to find the factors of a quadratic expression using the standard factorization method. I have explained the logic I used in the code as a comment at the beginning of the main JavaScript function and I have also listed the bugs I have detected so far at the end of the code. I depended solely on my logic based on previous exercises I have done to write this code, so I am hoping to learn a lot from your corrections. I don't know where the bugs are coming from in the code. I would be very grateful if you can help me figure out any. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Factorization of Quadratic Expression</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <div id="inner">
                <p>Quadratic Equation <span id="warning">MUST</span> be in this format 
                 <span id="format">ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c</span></p>
                <p>Use the caret symbol (<span id="caret">^</span>) for exponent, e.g x^2</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter quadratic equation" id="equation" required/><br/> 
                <br/>
                <button id="solve">Answer</button>
                <p id="solution"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // get button and paragraph to display solution

            let solution = document.getElementById('solution');
            let solve = document.getElementById('solve');

            // solve quadratic equation

            solve.onclick = function() {
                /* This is the main function of the code that finds the factors a quadratic expression.
                    I assume you already have an understanding of quadratic expressions but I will 
                    explain
                    the logic I used in the code. Assuming you have a quadratic expression f(x),
                    
                    f(x) = x^2 - 4x + 4
                    
                    I first multiplied the coefficient of x^2 which is +1 in this case with the constant 
                    which
                    is +4. Then I find two numbers whose product gives the value of the constant +4 and 
                    whose
                    sum gives the value of the coefficient of x which is -4. The numbers are -2 and -2.
                    Then I substitute the numbers with the value of the coefficient of x adding the 
                    literal.
                    
                    f(x) = x^2 - 2x - 2x + 4
                    
                    Next is grouping the first two quadratic coefficients and the last two using 
                    parentheses.
                    
                    f(x) = (x^2 - 2x) - (2x - 4) 
                    
                    The arithmetic symbol of the constant changes because once you expand it will give 
                    you the former expression.
                    Next is to finding the greatest common divisors of both groups and simplify.
                    
                    f(x) = x(x - 2) - 2(x - 2)
                    
                    Next is getting the common factors.
                    
                    f(x) = (x - 2)(x - 2) // Final answer
                    
                    Last line of code outputs the answer and it is the biggest challenge I am having 
                    because it seems I can only display a specific arithmetic symbol '+' (I chose to use 
                    this because I wrote the code using an all positive quadritic expression) in this 
                    case though it varies depending on the quadratic expression, like the one I used in 
                    this comment. */

                // get expression from input

                let equation = document.getElementById('equation').value;

                // validate expression (Only did this for fun and to get the feel of a real-world 
                   project)
    
                // if input was an empty string
                if(equation === '') {
                    solution.innerHTML = 'Error: No expression found! Please fill out the input field';
                }
                // if a symbol is missing or is there is none
                else if((equation.match(/(\+|\-)/g) === null) || (equation.match(/(\+|\-)/g).length < 2)) 
                {
                    solution.innerHTML = 'Error: Missing symbol in expression';
                }
                // if the expression is not in the specified format
                else if((equation.match(/\s/g).length < 2) || (equation.match(/\s/g).length > 2)) {
                    solution.innerHTML = 'Error: Missing or excess whitespace character in expression';
                }
                // if the exponent of x is not 2
                else if(equation[equation.indexOf('^') + 1] !== 2) {
                    solution.innerHTML = 'Error: Exponent of x must be equal to 2';
                }
                // none of these validations work by the way not sure why

                // get coefficient of x^2, x and the constant in the equation from input

                    array = equation.trim().split(''),
                    sign1 = array.indexOf('+'),
                    sign2 = array.lastIndexOf('+'),
                    getCoefficient_x2 = array.slice(0, array.indexOf(sign1 !== -1 ? '+' : '-') + 
                    2).join(''),
                    getCoefficient_x = array.slice(array.indexOf(sign1 !== -1 ? '+' : '-') + 2, 
                    array.lastIndexOf('+') - 1).join(''),
                    getConstant = array.slice(array.lastIndexOf(sign2 !==  -1? '+' : '-') + 2).join(''),
                    cox2 = parseInt(getCoefficient_x2) || 1,
                    cox = parseInt(getCoefficient_x) || 1,
                    c = parseInt(getConstant);

                // solving quadratic equation

                let product = cox2 * c,
                    sum = cox,
                    factors = getFactors(product),
                    sum_product = [],
                    _gcd = 0,
                    gcd_ = 0,
                    cfactor = [];

                // get factors whose product is equal to the constant and whose sum is equal to 
                   coefficient of x

                for(let i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
                    for(let j = 0; j < factors.length; j++) {
                        if((factors[i] * factors[j] === product) && (factors[i] + factors[j] === sum)) {
                            sum_product = [factors[j], factors[i]];
                        }
                    }
                }

                // grouping
                // get greatest common divisor of both groups

                _gcd = gcd(cox2, sum_product[0]);
                gcd_ = gcd(sum_product[1], c);

                // finding the common factors of the expression
                /* since the computer never makes a mistake I will only factor the first grouping as this 
                   will determine the other. */

                cfactor.push(cox2 / _gcd, sum_product[0] / _gcd);

                // expression of factorization is given as:

                solution.innerHTML = `(${_gcd > 1 ? _gcd : ''}x + ${gcd_})\
                (${cfactor[0] > 1 ? cfactor[0] : ''}x + ${cfactor[1]})`;
            }

            // function to get all negative and positive factors of a number

            function getFactors(number) {
                var factors = [],
                i = 0;

                if(number === undefined) number = 0;

                for(i = -number; i <= number; i++) {
                    if(number % i === 0) factors.push(i);
                }
                return factors;
            }

            // function to get the greatest common divisor of two numbers

            function gcd(num1, num2) {
                var numFac = [], gcd, maxNum = Math.max(num1, num2);
                for(let n = 1; n <= maxNum; n++) {
                    if(num1 % n == 0 && num2 % n == 0) {
                        numFac.push(n);
                    }
                }
                return Math.max(...numFac);
            }
            
            // Bugs
            /* (1) Outputs an unexpected value if the coefficient of x is greater than the constant.
               (2) Outputs an unexpected value if the expression uses a negative number. 
               (3) Outputs an unexpected value if coefficient of x and the constant have no common 
                   factors to determine the the sum and product respectively.
               (4) None of the validation codes works.
               (5) I am not sure how I can vary the signs of the symbol depending on the give expression.
            */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using this method? wouldn't the more simpler `x1 = (-b + sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)` and `x2 = (-b - sqrt( b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a)` done the trick?

Also, it would have been much easier to ask for the inputs in 3 seperate boxes instead of parsing an equation as you have done, that would cause so many errors, often only detected by exhaustive testing.

Comment: Because I am not trying to find the root x1, x2 of the expression but rather it's factors. I am aware of the quadratic formula you stated and I have written a separate code for that. But I like I like the thought of using 3 separate inputs. I will work on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

About the 4th bug: Your validations are working, the inner content of `solution` is being modified, but your final answer is overwriting it. You could add a boolean variable `valid = false` if one of your validations returns an error, and before changing the innerHTML of solution for the final answer, check if `valid = true`, if it is not, don't print your final answer.

Like this:

```
        var valid = true;
        if (equation === '') {
            solution.innerHTML = 'Error: No expression found! Please fill out the input field';
            valid = false;
        }
        // if a symbol is missing or is there is none
        else if ((equation.match(/(\+|\-)/g) === null) || (equation.match(/(\+|\-)/g).length < 2)) {
            solution.innerHTML = 'Error: Missing symbol in expression';
            valid = false;
        }
        // if the expression is not in the specified format
        else if ((equation.match(/\s/g).length < 2) || (equation.match(/\s/g).length > 2)) {
            solution.innerHTML = 'Error: Missing or excess whitespace character in expression';
            valid = false;
        }
        // if the exponent of x is not 2
        else if (equation[equation.indexOf('^') + 1] !== 2) {
            solution.innerHTML = 'Error: Exponent of x must be equal to 2';
            valid = false;
        }
```

And in your final answer:

```
        if (valid) {
            solution.innerHTML = `(${_gcd > 1 ? _gcd : ''}x + ${gcd_})\
            (${cfactor[0] > 1 ? cfactor[0] : ''}x + ${cfactor[1]})`;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank very much. I understand. I'm enlightened, it slipped my mind that the code
will continue to the next line even if one of the if statements is true. I might have thought I was returning the error message. Thanks again.